# Codeigniter - Formulário dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

tudo bem? Bem..Sou iniciante no mundo da Programação Web e estou tentando desenvolver um sistema em codeigniter. Será que podem me ajudar?
Estou tentando fazer um formulário dinâmico em que tenho um select que tem os meses do ano .. e eu gostaria que quando mudasse este select ele fizesse uma query no banco de dados MySQL e alterasse um input com o valor referente ao mês selcionado. O problema é que to querendo fazer com que isso ocorra sem dar submit no form pois o submit já cria uma espécie de fatura.
Para ficar mais fácil de entender. Eu estou querendo criar um form que gere uma fatura de acordo com o numero de visitas ocorridas no mes. Mes que eu escolho através do select. Ele pega o mês, procura no BD e muda o valor no input.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Quando eu preciso fazer um ajax em um controller eu faço assim:

```
<script>
   $(function (){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET', // ou post
           url: '<?= site_url('controller/action'); ?>',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: trataRetorno //function que irá tratar o retorno
       });
   });

   function trataRetorno(retorno){
       // código que irá manipular o retorno da query
       // utilize console.log(retorno) para depurar o retorno
   }
</script>
```

No controller:

```
public function action () {
    $this->load->model('Modelo_model');
    echo json_encode($this->Modelo_model->executa_query());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Para passar o valor do select para o php você pode fazer dessa forma:

javascript

```
// vamos criar um evento para capturar a mudança do valor no select... caso queira outro trigger é só alterar a linha abaixo.
$('select#IdDoSelect').on('change', function (){
    pegaValorDoMes($(this).val()); // se for utilizar um evento atribuido a outro objeto que não seja o seu select você também deve trocar esse $(this) pelo seletor apropriado do seu select
});

function pegaValorDoMes(valor) {
    $.ajax({
           type: 'GET', // ou post
           url: '<?= site_url('controller/action'); ?>',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: valor, // essa é a única novidade no javascript... serve para passar o valor do campo para o controller
           success: trataRetorno //function que irá tratar o retorno
       });
}

function trataRetorno(retorno){
       $('input#IdDoInput').val(retorno.valor);
}
```

config/routes.php

```
$routes['controller/action/(:num)'] = 'controller/action/$1'; //essa configuração permite que a sua action receba o valor do get feito pelo ajax
```

controllers/controller.php

```
public function action($mes) {
    // caso você opte por usar POST é só tirar as configurações de GET e utilizar o $this->input->post(mes); que irá funcionar normalmente
    $this->load->model('Modelo_model');
    echo json_encode($this->Modelo_model->executa_query($mes)); // essa é a linha que possibilita que o javascript trabalhe com o resultado em forma de objeto
}
```

models/Modelo_model.php

```
public function executa_query($mes){
    // aqui você vai realizar sua query normalmente retornando o array de resultado
    $this->db->select('valor');
    $this->db->where(array('mes' => $mes));
    $this->db->get('tabela')->row_array();
}
```

*Obs.: Lembrando que esse é um exemplo bem crú mesmo, apenas para te passar a idéia do que deve ser feito. Caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida é só comentar denovo que eu tento me aprofundar mais.*

Comment: Obrigado Raphael. Estou seguindo esta linha mesmo. Mas não sei como fazer para passar o valor do select para o PHP, fazer a query, retornar o valor pro AJAX e preencher o input. É nessa parte que fico perdido. Será que vc poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: @HarrisonVinicius Deu certo cara?

Comment: Opa. fala Ai amigo. Desculpe mas estou meio perdido em como fazer a query eu tenho 2 tabelas .. uma para O.S. e outra para Contratos.. e eu preciso contar quantas os do tipo "visitas extras" tiveram no mês e multiplicar pelo valor de visita extra que está na tabela do contrato e somar com o valor fixo mensal que também está na tabela contrato.. Quando eu faço direto (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM os WHERE status = 'Visita Extra' AND MONTH(dataFinal) = $mes")) ele funciona.. mas só funciona com a variável $mes fixa. Será que tem alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: como assim só funciona com a variável mês fixa? não entendi essa parte

Comment: @HarrisonVinicius alguma novidade cara?